# CodeIgniter JSON AJAX response with jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am trying to check the user username when typing it in the signup form and I have created the following function:

```
function validateSignupEmail(input){
    if (input == ""){
        return "Please enter your usernane.";
    }else if (input.length > 20){
        return "Your username cant exceed 20 characters.";
    }else{
        var type = "username_check";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: www+"signup/validate",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                type : type,
                input : input
            },
            success: function(data) {
                return data.response;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Inside the signup controller I have the following function called `validate()`

```
function validate(){
    $type = isset($_POST["type"]) ? $_POST["type"] : "";
    $input = isset($_POST["input"]) ? $_POST["input"] : "";

    if ($type == "username_check"){
        echo json_encode(array('response' => 'username available'));
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also I have the following code which shows what the username status in a `div`:

```
$("#signup_page form input[type='text']#username").keyup(function(){
    var text = validateSignupEmail($(this).val());
    console.log('text => '+text);
    $(".signup_ajax_live_messages").find(".username_check").text(text);
})
```

The thing is that I can't return the AJAX response inside the success: `function(){}`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the wonderful world of async, where you have to wait for the AJAX call to complete before processing the response.

Here's how you would process the response in your callback:

```
$("#signup_page form input[type='text']#username").keyup(function(){
    validateSignupEmail($(this).val());
});

function validateSignupEmail(input){
    if (input == ""){
        return "Please enter your usernane.";
    }else if (input.length > 20){
        return "Your username cant exceed 20 characters.";
    }else{
        var type = "username_check";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: www+"signup/validate",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                type : type,
                input : input
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $(".signup_ajax_live_messages").find(".username_check").text(data.response);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**On a side note:** Are you sure you want to make a new AJAX request on *every single keystroke*?

---

If you want to only check after the user has paused typing, use `setTimeout`:

```
var timer;
$("#signup_page form input[type='text']#username").keyup(function(){
    var text = $(this).text();
    timer && clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        validateSignupEmail(text);
    }, 400); // <-- this is the amount of milliseconds for the user to pause before making the AJAX call
});
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/dMhdD/

Comment: thanks, whats the best way to approach it instead of ajax-requesting on every single keystroke?

Comment: thanks, this seems to work when i keep pressing a button in my keyboard and then release it... it doesnt seem to work when i keep typing fast my name for example...

Comment: @fxuser - Check out the fiddle I just added.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot return a variable from the callback function.

When an AJAX request is dispatched, the application flow returns straight away even though the request has not yet completed. *Some time later*, the request completes, and the `success` callback is executed.

You should modify your `validateSignupEmail()` message to accept a callback.

```
function validateSignupEmail(input, callback){
    if (input == ""){
        return "Please enter your usernane.";
    }else if (input.length > 20){
        return "Your username cant exceed 20 characters.";
    }else{
        var type = "username_check";
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: www+"signup/validate",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                type : type,
                input : input
            },
            success: function(data) {
                callback(data.response);
            }
        });

        return "pending"; // let us know the AJAX request is in progress
    }
}
```

You'd then use it like this;

```
$("#signup_page form input[type='text']#username").keyup(function(){
    var text = validateSignupEmail($(this).val(), function (text) {
        console.log('text => '+text);
        $(".signup_ajax_live_messages").find(".username_check").text(text);
    });

    if (text !== "pending") {
        // text contains the error :(.
    }
})
```